# iTextSharp - How to set invisible signature field name

Tags: c#, itext

I am using iTextSharp 5 and [this code sample](http://gitlab.itextsupport.com/itextsharp/tutorial/blob/b45663fae16135239266e1f1eff2a3e266ac75d9/signatures/chapter4/C4_09_DeferredSigning/C4_09_DeferredSigning.cs) to implement deferred signing of PDF documents. The only difference from this example is that I need my signature to be invisible, so I'm not using `appearance.SetVisibleSignature` method.

But I don't know how to set the name of the signature field without this method (I need to save this field name in order to call `MakeSignature.SignDeferred` later). The property `PdfSignatureAppearance.FieldName` is read-only for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using `SetVisibleSignature`, and passing a rectangle of `(height, width) == (0,0)` together with the page number and the field name?

Comment: Hmm, this actually worked, but it seems a very weird (to say the least) way to do it. Is this feature supposed to work this way? Is it covered anywhere in the manual?

Comment: That is how invisible signatures usually are modelled inside pdfs.

Comment: @Samuel you should make that an answer.

Comment: Like mkl said, it is how invisible signatures are modelled internally. It's indeed a weird way to use the method, we cleaned it up a bit in iText7 (`fieldName` can be set by the `PdfSigner` object directly).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `PdfSignature#SetVisibleSignature` and pass a `rectangle` with height and width equal to zero in addition to the `fieldName` and `pageIndex`.